# Learning to map vectors to vectors

Tags: regression, time-series, graphical-model, supervised-learning

Say we want to learn a function:

$f(\mathbf{x} \in \mathbf{R}^p) \rightarrow \mathbf{y} \in \mathbf{R}^q$

where $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are vectors representing time series.

We have multiple examples of this mapping, i.e.:

$$\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{x_0}\\...\\\mathbf{x_N}\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{y_0}\\...\\\mathbf{y_N} \end{pmatrix} $$

What type of problem is this? Is it a regression problem? If so, what metrics (loss functions) and methods would be appropiate for this problem? Anything specifically available in Python?

Comment: I am a bit confused with your notation. Specifically $\mathbf{t}_x$ vs $\mathbf{t}_X$ and $t_X$. Perhaps standard (statistical) notation like $X_t$ or $X_{it}$ will help? Otherwise, example data will also help clarify things.

Comment: Thanks @qoheleth I just simplified the notation significantly. Hopefully it is a lot clearer now.

Comment: Did you really intend to imply that $N+1=p=q$?

Comment: @whuber: I think $N$ is the number of paired sample time series, each of length $p$ (for the series that is mapped from) or $q$ (for the series that is mapped to).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like this the same problem as classifying elements of $\mathbf{x}$ with integers $\{1, \dots, N\}$. Not sure if that helps at all.

Comment: @ssdecontrol: If $f$ is linear and $q=1$ (weird time series, then ;) , it would be usual linear regression. If additionally $y$ would have a discrete domain, it would be classification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem falls to the class called [structured-output learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured-output_learning). First, you need to define a function $F(\mathbf{y}; \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{w})$ that scores predictions. It is supposed to return large values for the correct $\mathbf{y}$ and those similar to it. It is parametrized by the vector $\mathbf{w}$; usually $F$ depends linearly on $\mathbf{w}$. At test time, the decision is thus made by maximization:

$\hat{\mathbf{y}} = \arg\!\max_{\bar{\mathbf{y}}} F(\bar{\mathbf{y}}; \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{w})$.

So $F$ should be chosen the way to perform this maximization efficiently. See below for an example.

At training time, you need to find the parameters $\mathbf{w}^*$ such that for each training example $\mathbf{x}_i$ the corresponding prediction $\hat{\mathbf{y}}_i$ should be close $\mathbf{y}_i$ in some sense. Similarly to regression, it is unlikely to match perfectly, so one needs to define a loss function.

One such method is provided by [structured SVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_SVM). The methods tries to find parameters $\mathbf{w}$ to maximize the margin

$F(\mathbf{y}_i; \mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{w}) - \max_{\bar{\mathbf{y}}: \bar{\mathbf{y}} \ne \mathbf{y}_i} F(\bar{\mathbf{y}}; \mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{w})$

for each training example $(\mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{y}_i)$. To account for similarity in $\mathbf{y}$'s, it is usually augmented with the empirical loss function $\Delta(\bar{\mathbf{y}}; \mathbf{y})$ that measures some sort of distance; for discrete vectors it may measure [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance). Thus, for each training example we want to maximize the following:

$F(\mathbf{y}_i; \mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{w}) - \max_{\bar{\mathbf{y}}} \{ F(\bar{\mathbf{y}}; \mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{w}) + \Delta(\bar{\mathbf{y}}; \mathbf{y}_i) \}$.

The idea is to strive for the larger margin if $\bar{\mathbf{y}}$ is more different from $\mathbf{y}_i$. We can put it together and add $L_2$ regularization to get the SVM-style optimization problem:

$\textrm{minimize}_{\mathbf{w}, \boldsymbol{\xi}} \quad \frac{\|\mathbf{w}\|^2}{2} + C \sum_{i=0}^N \xi_i,$

$\textrm{s.t.} \quad F(\mathbf{y}_i; \mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{w}) - \max_{\bar{\mathbf{y}}} \{ F(\bar{\mathbf{y}}; \mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{w}) + \Delta(\bar{\mathbf{y}}; \mathbf{y}_i) \} \ge -\xi_i, \quad \forall i.$

It is not trivial to solve, but there are well-studied methods that perform it, including the cutting-plane algorithm and subgradient descent. For implementations, you can try [SVMstruct](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/tj/svm_light/svm_struct.html) and [pystruct](https://pystruct.github.io/).

---

What is left is the design of the scoring function $F$. It really depends on the problem you solve, but often some kind of graphical model is useful. Given that your data are sequential, something like [Hidden Markov Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model) or [some its generalization](http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1162&context=cis_papers) may be useful. For example, you may consider the following “factorization”:

$F(\mathbf{y}; \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{w}) = \psi(y_{0}; \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{w}) + \sum_{j=1}^q \Big( \phi(y_{j-1}, y_{j}; \mathbf{w}) + \psi(y_{j}; \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{w}) \Big).$

It allows performing maximization over $\mathbf{y}$ in $\mathcal{O}(q)$ time using dynamic programming. The potential functions $\psi$ and $\phi$ should depend linearly on (different parts of) $\mathbf{w}$, but specific form depends on your problem (in particular, if the output variables are discrete or continuous). You also need to figure out the components of $\mathbf{x}$ the potential function depends on.

This form of scoring functions accounts for the “correlations” of neighbouring $y$'s, but it is possible to add higher-order connections at some computational cost (i.e. potentials like $\phi_4(y_{j-4}, y_{j}; \mathbf{w})$). SVMstruct library contains an example of training HMM.

Note that in case of such sequential models training can be done by maximizing likelihood, which leads to a different objective function, but in general case it is infeasible. See [this paper](http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1162&context=cis_papers) for more details on probabilistic training of sequential models.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is too general to be useful. A solution would be to map each $\mathbf{x}_i$ to $\mathbf{y}_i$ and to continue this mapping arbitrarily on $\mathbb{R}^p\setminus\{\mathbf{x}_i|i=1,\ldots,N\}$. So there is no unique solution for exactly this general problem. The function space $f$ belongs to is too large. If you could restrict $f$ to some parametrized function family (like polynomial regression) it might become feasible.

(Maybe you edit your question to make it more precise)